# Why doesn't jQuery Append work for the end of HTML List Items?

Tags: jquery, dom, list, append

I'm trying to clone a list item, and then append it to the bottom of that cloned list item, note that it should be below the list item being cloned, not at the bottom of the list as I can do that myself. The purpose is to use it with jQuery.ui sortable.

Everything is working fine, in fact I can even get the cloning and the appending right. However, it appends it **before** the closing `</li>` tag, and for the life of me I can't force it to append **after** this tag.

This is the HTML Markup:

```
<ul id="column-2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <div class="label">feature</div>
        <div class="action">
            <div class="delete"></div>
            <div class="other"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The part we're concerned with is `class="other"` which upon being clicked on will duplicate the list item.

This is the jQuery so far:

```
// This works fine
$(".other").click(function() {

    // This needs to be set (global) to be used later on in some future code.
    actionTarget = this;        

    // This grabs the whole list item
    var targetStory = $(actionTarget).parent().parent();

    // This clones the list item, as well as appending 
    // that clone to the cloned list item
    $(targetStory).clone().appendTo(targetStory);

})
```

This works well, it grabs the list item, clones it, then dumps it on the screen - but in the wrong place :(

```
<ul id="column-2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <div class="label">feature</div>
        <div class="action">
            <div class="delete"></div>
            <div class="other"></div>
        </div>
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <div class="label">feature</div>
            <div class="action">
                <div class="delete"></div>
                <div class="other"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Anyone have any idea why it's not appending to the end of the list item being cloned, and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

perhaps you want to use [after](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after) instead of appendTo

Comment: Yep! This does the trick, thanks cobbal

$(targetStory).after(targetStory.clone());

Comment: For reference:
http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/appendTo   States that the element you have , it will be inside it - just placed at the end of the content inside it. Hence the word, Appending.  .After like you found is the way to go.

Comment: True, I missed the clarification of "inside it", too much skimming.

Answer (score 1):

i think what you want is this:

```
$(targetStory).clone().appendTo(targetStory.parent());
```

Comment: Almost, it's something Id' already tried. Instead, it adds it to the bottom of the list, rather than after the list item being cloned.

Answer (score 0):

I think [insertAfter](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/insertAfter) is what you're looking for.  after would insert the original node after the clone, rather than the clone after the original node.  Something like this should work:

```
$(targetStory).clone().inserAfter(targetStory);
```

Comment: Thanks Mishac, cobbal already managed to nab the answer! $(targetStory).after(targetStory.clone());