# javascript created input[type="text'] doesn't post it's variable

Tags: javascript, html

hey there, I'm creating a series of input elements and for some reason their values aren't `$_POST`ing.  Any light shed on the subject would be appreciated!

My current code is as follows:

`javascript`

```
   Afields = 1;
    function addAdultInput() {
        if (Afields != 10) {
            document.getElementById('adultMembers').innerHTML += "<input type='text' value='' name='adult_members_"+Afields+"' /><br />";
            Afields += 1;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('adultMembers').innerHTML += "Only 10 Adult Member fields allowed.";
            document.getElementById('addAdultMember').disabled=true;
        }
    }
```

`HTML`

```
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <tr>
    <td class="style12" valign="top">Adult Members' Names:<br /><small>10 Max </small><input id="addAdultMember" type="button" onclick="addAdultInput()" name="add" value="Add Adult" /></td>
    <td id="adultMembers">
        <span class="erorr">*for paid members only</span><br />
        <input type='text' value='' name='adult_members_0' /><br />

    </td>
  </tr>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Register">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full and complete answer:

Using the innerHTML method doesn't actually add the DOM element to the source of the page, preventing any information entered into the element from `$_POST`ing.  I solved this issue by using `jQuery` and the `append()` feature.

`HTML`

```
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <tr>
    <td class="style12">Adult Members' Names:</td>
    <td class="style12"><small>10 Max</small> <span class="erorr">*for paid members only</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="style12" valign="top"><small>Click to Add Fields</small> <input id="addAdultMember" type="button" name="add" value="Add Adult" /></td>
    <td><ol id="adultMembers" class="style12">
        <li><input  type='text' value='' name='adult_members[]' /></li>
    </ol></td>
  </tr>
  </form>
```

`jQuery`

```
var Acurrent = 1;
function addAdultField(){
    Acurrent++;
    if(Acurrent <= 10){
        var strToAdd = "<li><input type='text' value='' name='adult_members[]' /></li>";
        $('#adultMembers').last().append(strToAdd);
    } else {
        $("#addAdultMember").attr("disabled", true);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#addAdultMember").click(addAdultField);

});
```

Thanks to the Sources:

Sinan Taifour (below)
[javascript created input[type="text'] doesn't post it's variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475489/javascript-created-inputtypetext-doesnt-post-its-variable/2475847#2475847)

[Why doesn't jQuery Append work for the end of HTML List Items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704858/why-doesnt-jquery-append-work-for-the-end-of-html-list-items)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is what is particularly happening with you, but generally using `innerHTML` to add input fields is not recommended.

Instead, you should use `createElement()` and `appendChild()`, or you can alternatively use a library like JQuery or Prototype. You can find tons of help on using these two functions online.

Comment: thanks sinan, you did put me on the path to finding the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Two suggestions:

1. Put a web inspector (like the one in Safari) on your form and take a look at the DOM structure after you've added the fields.
2. You could just name all the fields `adult_members[]` and PHP will create an array for you out of the post variables.

I assume you've already put a print_r($_POST) at the top of your page to make sure the problem isn't elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Feel free to check out the code on page @ www.riverhouseclub.com.  I've commented out the function that writes information to the database, so feel free to test out the form.  I've added the print_r function so you and whoever else can see that the post values, in fact, disappear when an element is added. Almost like the innerHTML process removes the elements from the dom.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting your `form` inside a `td`. That is giving you a lot of trouble. Wrap the whole `table` (or more if need be) in the `form`. All of your inputs need to be in the form. Always [validate your HTML](http://validator.nu/) to avoid problems like this.

Comment: The problem is having to do with the method of inserting new elements into the dom.  Using innerHTML causes the post contents to evaporate.  Please also realize that This is an annotated snippet of code from the file in question.  Last thing, the form element is started outside the `tr` rather than inside a `td`.  Thanks anyway.